# When exposing IQueryable when does DataContext get disposed?

Tags: linq-to-sql, repository-pattern, dispose

As seems to be popular at the moment, if you implement a repository as simply

```
IQueryable<T> FetchAll<T>();
```

using LINQ to SQL, then the repository must set up a DataContext which remains available outside of the repository.

So my question is, How does the DataContext get Disposed?
What if an exception is generated by the code outside of the repository?
Will it be leaking database connections?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Why you dont need to call dispose on DataContext](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/08/20/asp-net-mvc-tip-34-dispose-of-your-datacontext-or-don-t.aspx)

Summary the DataContext opens a connection when the query is called (when you access the data), and closes it when the query is over.

Comment: Thankyou, that is great!! I knew I must be missing something as nowhere have I seen any examples that expose IQueryable<T> dispose the  DataContext

Answer (score 2):

Make your repository implement IDisposable (and Dispose of the DataContext when the repository is Disposed). Now the API for your repository is something like

```
using (var repository=new MyRepository) //or use a ServiceLocator or Factory
{
    var myObjects = repository.FetchAll().Where(obj=>obj.Foo == "bar");
    //do something with myObjects
}
```

And now your repository will properly dispose of your DataContext and all is well in the world.

Comment: Hey Mike, I this kind of thought in the back of my mind, but not yet seen it anywhere. All the books/blogs etc. just use IQueryable straight up. Is making the repository IDisposable 'the done thing'?

Comment: Looks like it's a moot point. But making your repository Disposable allows you to do tricks like keeping the ObjectContext around for attaching new objects to it, and creating transactions.